# Using sed to replace matches of a string

Tags: bash, sed

I have various java files that have the following statement in their methods:

```
      var1.setMaximumSize((-1));
```

The statement starts with 6 white spaces.

I am trying to delete these lines or replace them with an empty string. I have tried the following script with no success:

```
for fl in *.java; do
    mv $fl $fl.old
    sed 's/^\s*var[0-9]+\.setMaximumSize\(\(-1\)\);$//g' $fl.old > $fl
    rm -f $fl.old
done
```

Comment: Can somebody tell me how should I make it to navigate a directory tree?

Comment: Never mind, I have managed to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many implementations of sed do not accept modern regex patterns.  The ones that might be problematic in your expression are \s and +.  (Try \+).  Also, sed treats ( as a normal character which must be escaped to become a meta character.  You could try:

```
$ sed '/^      var[0-9][0-9]*.setMaximumSize((-1));$/d'
```

Comment: It is a problem with my implementation, thanks a bunch for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I think it doesn't work because you are using extended regexes (e.g. the `+` quantifier), so you have to use `sed -r`.

You may also perform an in-place edit, from `man sed`:

> ```
>    -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>
>           edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
> ```

So this should work:

```
sed -r -i'' -e's/^\s*var[0-9]+\.setMaximumSize\(\(-1\)\);$//g' *.java
```

Answer (score 1):

If your *sed* implementation supports the -i (in-place) option:

```
sed  -i '/^ \{6\}var[0-9][0-9]*.setMaximumSize((-1));$/d' *java
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use literal parentheses, you don't need to escape it. `sed` interprets escaped parentheses as a grouping. Also, you need to escape the '+' to use it correctly:

```
sed 's/^\s*var[0-9]\+\.setMaximumSize((-1));$//g' $fl.old > $fl
```